# Sync only especifics columns in SymmetricDS

Tags: symmetricds

This is my table:

ITEM_PRECO_VENDA (
ID_ITEM,
ID_LOJA,
PRECO,
CUSTO,
CIDADE)

I want to replicate only the column CIDADE, how can i do this?

Please, help.

Comment: I would add a table CIDADE(ID, NOME), replace the column ITEM_PRECO_VENDA.CIDADE with a column ITEM_PRECO_VENDA.CIDADE_ID with foreign key constraint that it referenced the primary key CIDADE.ID and sync only the table CIDADE

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do: On table SYM_TRIGGER it has the column INCLUDED_COLUMN_NAMES you put the columns that you want to replicate, and it will ignore the others.